# Can anyone reproduce or explain this possible Mathematica 13 bug that causes invisible output style sometimes? (ISSUE GONE AFTER COMPUTER RESTART)

Tags: output-formatting

I came across this odd behavior in Mathematica 13. The output to the following line is invisible.

```
 Style["Blah", FontColor -> Hue[NCache[Rational[7, 12], 0.5833333333333334`], 1, 1]]
```

However, a number of similar expressions output the results I expect. The following two lines both output colored text

```
 Style["Blah", FontColor -> Hue[NCache[Rational[7, 12], 0.5833333333333333`], 1, 1]]
 Style["Blah", FontColor -> Hue[NCache[Rational[7, 13], 0.5384615384615385`], 1, 1]]
```

I came across this while using ListPlot to plot some series with PlotStyle -> (Hue[#/12]&/@Range[12]) and PlotMarkers -> (ToString[#]&/@Range[12]). I notices that the 7th series was missing which led me here. I cannot reproduce this result in Mathematica 12.3.

Edit. Added image
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Edit2. Windows 10, Mathematica v13.0.1.

Edit3. After restarting my computer, I no longer have this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! None of the expressions above give invisible result [on my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RbAb.png). Can you post a screenshot? Which operating system do you use?

Comment: On v12.2.0, I get three colored line as shown by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dodOC.png) image.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior your describe in MMA 13.01 on Linux (on the cloud). I get a pale blue Blah.

Comment: Windows 10 MMA 13.0.1 also get a blue "Blah"

Comment: Can you include the output of `$Version` in your question, for reference?

Comment: Windows 11 Pro, Mathematica 13.0.1, and I get a blue Blah.

Comment: What is the ListPlot call that had an issue?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the issue you describe with 13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021).

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the issue.  On macOS Monterey (12.4), I get a $\color{cyan}{\text{Blah}}$ with both MMA 12.2.0 and 13.0.1.  You could try reinstalling MMA and seeing if the issue persists.

Comment: @mrkcw, I would start by updating your video card driver.

Comment: We don't really have a "no-repro" close reason, so this comment will have to do.